# getting id by using autocomplete jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to insert `ui.item.id` (which is `ivlist.ivac_id` from controller)
into `<input type="text" id="vac_ivac_id" name="vac_ivac_id"/>`
but it doesn't work.

I assume i did something wrong with ui, or select:function. I've been going through googling about autocomplete for past hours, but can't find what's wrong.

below i attached my source code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#vac_name').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/searchIVac.do",
                data: {
                    search: $("#vac_name").val()
                },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                success: function (jsonData) {
                    response($.map(jsonData.ivlist, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.ivac_name,
                            label: item.ivac_name,
                            id: item.ivac_id
                        };
                    }));
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    alert(ui.item.id);
                    $("#vac_ivac_id").val(ui.item.id);
                },
                selectFirst: false,
                minLength: 2,
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#vac_name').val(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
                },
            });
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="vac_name" name="vac_name" />
            <input type="hidden" id="vac_ivac_id" name="vac_ivac_id" value="0" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not closed properly the source/ajax call parenthesis/braces.

If you look at your code alla the autocomplete function are inside the ajax option, not part of the autocomplete.

The correct code must be something like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#vac_name').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/searchIVac.do",
                data: {
                    search: $("#vac_name").val()
                },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                success: function (jsonData) {
                    response($.map(jsonData.ivlist, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.ivac_name,
                            label: item.ivac_name,
                            id: item.ivac_id
                        };
                    }));
                }
            }) //<--close the ajax call
        }, //<--close source option
        select: function (event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.id);
            $("#vac_ivac_id").val(ui.item.id);
        },
        selectFirst: false,
        minLength: 2,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $('#vac_name').val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
    });

});
```